# Github actions mask with asterisks my accessToken in the logs

Tags: curl, github-actions

So I have a github actions job that does a curl

```
      - name: Get Token
        run: |
          accessToken=$( \
          curl -k --request POST https://$LB_URL/auth \
            --header 'Host: some.url.com' \
            --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
            --data-raw '{ 
                "type": "something",
                "payload": {
                    "address": "sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsd",
                    "signature": "sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsd",
                    "time": "2021-01-08 06:42:57 UTC"
                }
            }' | jq -r '.accessToken' )
          echo $accessToken
```

and in the github workflow logs I get this...

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100   843  100   508  100   335   3937   2596 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  6585
***
```

Does Github somehow understad that this is sensitive data and masks it?

Cause when I get from the same response `.user.id` it prints it fine.

And finally, for debugging purposes in a private repo, how can I tell it to unmask it ?

Comment: Please keep in mind to ask one thing per question.

Comment: Ok. I just though that they are too closely related. Noted.